How can I add request-specific span attributes for requests in a WebFlux Application
I am trying to add additional attributes to my OpenTelemetry Spans, i'm running Spring Boot (3.3.4) with web-application-type: reactive enabled.
I need to add specific pre-defined attributes and also need to respond to specific incoming headers, adding attributes to the current span depending on their value.
But currently the only way i'm able to add attributes is using a CustomSpanProcessor, but i'm only able to make this approach work for the pre-defined attributes, as i'm unable to add access request-specific informations (RequestContextHolder is not available for example).
@Component
public class CustomSpanProcessor implements SpanProcessor {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Context parentContext, ReadWriteSpan span) {
       span.setAttribute("customAttribute", "value"))
    }

    //other interface methods...
}

I have tried to get request-specific informations in the processor using a WebFilter
public class TracingRequestFilter implements WebFilter {
    Map<String, String> attr = Map.of("dynamicAttribute", getValue(exhange));
    return chain.filter(exchange)
                .contextWrite(reactor.util.context.Context.of(WEB_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES, attr));
}

And then accessing it in the onStart of the CustomProcessor
@Component
public class CustomSpanProcessor implements SpanProcessor {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Context parentContext, ReadWriteSpan span) {
        Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
            Map<String, Object> attributes = ctx.get(TracingRequestFilter.WEB_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES);
            attributes.forEach((s, o) -> span.setAttribute(s, o.toString()));
            return Mono.empty();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .subscribe(); // as i'm not allowed to block the thread..
    }

    //other interface methods...
}

